# como sumo los datos en una columna de DataGridView en c#?

Tags: c#

No encuentro la manera de hacer la suma de una columna en una datagridview.

Comment: y qué has intentado en código?

Answer (score 1):

Hice una aplicación de escritorio a modo de ejemplo. En donde defino un datatable con datos para alimentar una grilla. Finalmente hay un boton que computa la cantidad de articulos en total. En este ejemplo use enteros.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CargaDatos();
        }

        public void CargaDatos()
        {

            DataTable tabla = GetTable();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = tabla;
            dataGridView1.Show();
        }
        static DataTable GetTable()
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable tabla = new DataTable();
            ds.Tables.Add(tabla);
            tabla.Columns.Add("Articulo", typeof(string));
            tabla.Columns.Add("Cantidad", typeof(Int32));         
            tabla.Rows.Add("A",100);
            tabla.Rows.Add("B",200);
            tabla.Rows.Add("C",300);

            return tabla;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int suma = 0;          
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells["Cantidad"].Value != null)
                    suma += (Int32)row.Cells["Cantidad"].Value;
            }
            MessageBox.Show(suma.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

En el manejador del boton se observa la suma que en este caso se hizo por el nombre de la columna definida como "Cantidad", tambien puede accederse por número de columna en vez del nombre.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int suma = 0;          
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells["Cantidad"].Value != null)
                    suma += (Int32)row.Cells["Cantidad"].Value;
            }
            MessageBox.Show(suma.ToString());
        }
    }
```

El mismo método que el anterior pero por número quedaría de la siguiente manera

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int suma = 0;          
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells[1].Value != null) //1 es "Cantidad"
                    suma += (Int32)row.Cells[1].Value;
            }
            MessageBox.Show(suma.ToString());
        }
```

Salida por pantalla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos.

Comment: Por mas que esto conteste la pregunta, trata de no contestar pregunta que no demuestran nada de informacion ni nada que se haya intentado.

Comment: Ok gbianchi. Saludos.